# Configure nodejs as SP with passport-saml and OpenAM as IDP

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml-2.0, openam

I deployed OpenAM and created hosted IDP. Then I want to configure NodeJs as Service Provider and implement SSO with passport-saml. For this, I have to register my node.js application as a remote service provider.

- OpenAM deployment url - http://ndcdr001s:8081/OpenAM-12.0.0
- NodeJS application deployment url - http://ndcui.local:9000/

I have two questions:

1. In order to register NodeJs application as a remote service provider, I must tell to OpenAM URL where metadata is located. How I can get metadata with passport-saml ?
2. How to configure passport-saml to work with OpenAM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I configured passport-saml like this :**

```
return new SamlStrategy(
    {

entryPoint: "http://ndcdr001s:8081/OpenAM-12.0.0/saml2/jsp/idpSSOInit.jsp?"
      + "metaAlias=/idp"
      + "&spEntityID=http://ndcui.local:9000/metadata/",

      callbackUrl: 'http://ndcui.local:9000/login/callback/',

      logoutUrl: "http://ndcdr001s:8081/OpenAM-12.0.0/saml2/jsp/idpSingleLogoutInit.jsp?"
      + "binding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
      + "&RelayState=http://ndcui.local:9000/saml/logout/callback",

      issuer: 'http://ndcui.local:9000/'
    },
    function (profile, done) {

      return done(null,
        {
          id: profile.id,
          email: profile.email,
         // displayName: profile.cn,
        //  firstName: profile.givenName,
         // lastName: profile.sn,
          sessionIndex: profile.sessionIndex,
          saml: {
            nameID: profile.nameID,
            nameIDFormat: profile.nameIDFormat,
            token:profile.getAssertionXml()
          }
        });
    });
```

Then I registered "http://ndcui.local:9000/metadata/" as SP in OpenAM.

**I created metadata for SP manually like this:** and put under the this link "http://ndcui.local:9000/metadata/"

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="http://ndcui.local:9000/metadata/">
  <SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">

    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"  Location="http://ndcui.local:9000/logout"  Response_Location="http://ndcui.local:9000/saml/logout/callback"/>

    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://ndcui.local:9000/login/callback" index="0"/>
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post" Location="http://ndcui.local:9000/login/callback" index="1"/>
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="http://ndcui.local:9000/login/callback" index="2"/>
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01" Location="http://ndcui.local:9000/login/callback" index="3"/>
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:holder-of-key:SSO:browser" Location="http://ndcui.local:9000/login/callback" index="4"/>
   </SPSSODescriptor>
  <ContactPerson contactType="technical">
    <GivenName>Administrator</GivenName>
    <EmailAddress>noreply@example.org</EmailAddress>
  </ContactPerson>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

**And my routes:**

```
app.get('/metadata', function (req, res) {

 //Send custom metadata
      res.type('application/xml');
      res.sendfile(__dirname + "/metadata.xml");
    }
  );

app.get("/login", passport.authenticate('saml',
      {
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/login",
      })
  );

app.post('/login/callback', passport.authenticate('saml',
      {
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true
      }),
    function (req, res) {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  );

app.get('/logout', auth.requiresLogin, function (req, res) {

    req.user.nameID = req.user.saml.nameID;

    req.user.nameIDFormat = req.user.saml.nameIDFormat;

    samlStrategy.logout(req, function (err, request) {
      if (!err) {
        res.redirect(request);
      }
    });

  });

app.get('/saml/logout/callback', auth.requiresLogin, function (req, res) {
    //Logout user
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');

  });
```

Link to full Implementation (you will want to google translate the page)

https://qiita.com/nsp01/items/d1b328e5698f6ffd8345

Comment: You didnt have to pass certificate in the strategy?

Comment: In that case I didn't use the certificate.

Comment: ok login part worked for me but it's saying `samlStrategy.logout` is not a function , can you elaborate on this samlStrategy variable declaration for me it is declared as : `var samlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;`

Comment: You have to export  "return new SamlStrategy.... " this part of the code in your module and call it wherever you need it.

Comment: 'use strict';

var SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;

module.exports = function () {

  return new SamlStrategy(...
}

Comment: Anyone have any ideas of how to deal with SOAP in this situation

Answer (score 0):

If your SP does not provide any metadata, then you can generate the metadata using the ssoadm [create-metadata-templ](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/12.0.0/reference/index.html#ssoadm-create-metadata-templ) command that should create a nice metadata template for you, which you should be able to customize as needed.